# load external whitelist for firefox noscript plugin

Tags: firefox, sync, noscript

I'd like to have the noscript whitelist stored in dropbox (or sync'ed somehow) so I can have multiple computers sync'ed off the same whitelist.  Does anyone know how I could configure this?  I don't know where the whitelist file is stored, but if it's not possible to configure noscript to use an external file, then maybe it could be symlinked or possibly put into a git repo, etc.  I would just like to avoid manually exporting and then importing the file on multiple computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For my own reference, since no one answered)

The Noscript whitelist information is stored in the Firefox profile.  I found some (somewhat old) information about sync'ing a Firefox profile using dropbox here:

[sync Firefox using Dropbox](http://www.jonefox.com/blog/2009/11/16/how-to-sync-firefox-across-multiple-computers-using-dropbox/)

This solution uses symlinks to redirect the Firefox profile to Dropbox.  You would need to create symlinks on all computers which need to be synchronized.  On Windows, it looks like you use the MKLINK command, which may require administrator privileges.  I will try this solution out when I get the chance.

It also looks like you could use the built in Firefox sync.  There is a Noscript setting in Firefox -> about:config called "Noscript.sync.enabled".  It is set to false by default.  Enabling this will presumably allow the Noscript settings to be synchronized by Firefox sync.  Interestingly, it is possible to create your own Firefox sync server.  This would probably be overkill but seems like it would be fun to try.

Answer (score 2):

As of NoScript 2.6.9.3 the whitelist is stored in the `prefs.js` file inside the Firefox profile (key: `capability.policy.maonoscript.sites`).

I guess it should be possible to extract/replace this information with a script.